# How to specify a Regular Expression for LocalSessionFactoryBean mappingLocations

Tags: java, regex, spring, hibernate, configuration

In my application, I have specified the below configuration for automatically picking up all the HBM files under a specific folder in the classpath.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="mappingLocations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:hbms/**/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Now, for a new requirement, there is a need to create multiple HBM files with named queries specific to database. The HBM file names will be of the pattern  test.DB.hbm.xml. For example, *test.oracle.hbm.xml* and *test.db2.hbm.xml*. In addition to these, there are the old regular HBM files (for mapping to tables) with name format as table1.hbm.xml, table2.hbm.xml, etc. also present in the same folder.

Using the above pattern, hibernate loading of the files fails, due to duplicate named queries in the new hbm files (since the name would be same in all such files).

The requirement is now to load the regular HBM files and also the DB specific HBM files. Is it possible to achieve this by using a regular expression as below?

```
classpath:hbms/**/*.(.${dbType}).hbm.xml
```

In the above example, *dbType* is available as a Spring environment property. My attempt with these changes resulted in none of the HBM files being loaded (including the old ones).

Am I doing something wrong with the regular expression or is it not possible to do this via XML configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: The path is probably being resolved by [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html), so it is not a standard regular expression. So as a first step I would get rid of those parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can have each database specific config files be stored in a separate folder and then your config looks like this:

   ```
   classpath:hbms/**/${dbType}/*.hbm.xml
   ```
2. You can have them follow he pattern you provided, but change the configuration to

   ```
   classpath:hbms/**/*${dbType}.hbm.xml
   ```

To load common files, you need to rename them to include something you can match, like:

```
one.hbm.xml
```

becoming:

```
common-one.hbm.xml
```

Then the configuration might look like this:

```
    classpath:hbms/**/common-*.hbm.xml
    classpath:hbms/**/*${dbType}.hbm.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Vlad. The first approach is not possible for us at the moment since the build scripts will need to be modified. I tried the 2nd approach you provided. However, with it the regular hbm files (of the format one.hbm.xml) do not get loaded. Sorry, if that was not clear from the question description. I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Finally, we decided to modify the build scripts and go with the first approach you suggested (storing config files in separate folders).